# How to identify if parameters are estimable, after defining a design matrix

Tags: self-study, generalized-linear-model, matrix

I need to define a design matrix $X$ so that it fits this scenario:
For $1\leq i< j \leq 5$, where $i$ are competitors and $j$ are different competitors. Their score is $y_{ij} =$ score of player $i$ minus score of player $j$.

$$Y_{ij} =\beta_i - \beta_j+\varepsilon_{ij}.$$

$\beta_i,\ldots,\beta_5$  are unknown parameters. $\varepsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2I)$.

The $X$ matrix has to represent only 4 matches: $y_{12}$, $y_{34}$, $y_{25}$, $y_{15}$. and then be usable in general linear form $y=X\beta+\varepsilon$.

A couple challenges:

(a) I've never done this before. I am thinking I should use zeros, ones and negative ones. Am I right in putting ones and negative ones in the two parameter columns for a match, and zeros in the parameter columns that aren't playing in the match?

(b) How do I decide if a couple comparisons can be made, $\beta_1 - \beta_2$ and $\beta_1 - \beta_3$?

$X =$ in the row order  $y_{12}$, $y_{34}$, $y_{25}$, $y_{15}$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  -1  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0  & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
1  &  0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I further have $E(y)$ = 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_1 \\
\mu_2 \\
\mu_3 \\
\mu_4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I know of 2 ways to see if it's estimable. The first is by seeing if a matrix $A$ exists such that $Ae(Y) = AX\beta.$ The other way is the way I need to practice, so where I look to you: By seeing if there is a given linear combination of the elements of beta that can be written as a linear combination of the elements of E(y).

Comment: Where you say "score of player $i-j$" (which seems to idendity one player with the number that is the difference between the numbers $i$ and $j$), might you have meant "score of player $i$ minus score of player $j$"? $\qquad$

Comment: Should this be understood as meaning that if two players compete then the data available to you is only the _difference_ between the numbers of points they scored?  E.g. if player $1$ gets $13$ points and player $2$ gets $17$, then we learn only that player $2$ got $4$ points more than player $1$? $\qquad$

Comment: I've seen this question before as a homework problem.  Please add the self-study tag.

Comment: Note that $y_{12}$ is properly coded as y_{12}, and $\varepsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2 I)$ as \varepsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2 I). I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

The design matrix you have set up is not quite right. Since this is a homework problem, I'll give you hints and help you through the problem.  The key to setting up your design matrix involves, understanding what Y represents.  In this case, is represents, the difference between player $i$'s score and player $j$'s score.  So, to get started set up the matrices (in doing so, I'm ignoring the error terms $\epsilon_{ij}$, but remember those are important!) accordingly:

$\begin{bmatrix}
    y_{12}\\
    y_{34}\\
    y_{25}\\
    y_{15}\\
\end{bmatrix}=X\begin{bmatrix}
    \beta_1\\
    \beta_2\\
    \beta_3\\
    \beta_4\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    \beta_1-\beta_2\\
    \beta_3-\beta_4\\
    \beta_2-\beta_5\\
    \beta_1-\beta_5\\
\end{bmatrix}$

The $X$ matrix is a 4 $\times$5 matrix, where each column is represented by a $\beta$.  So you need to ask yourself, what should the elements of $X$ be so that when you multiply $X\beta$ you get the differences of $\beta$s shown on the right hand sight of the matrix equation above.  The elements should consists of only 1, -1, and 0.  Once you do this correction, it should be fairly straight forward to answer your remaining questions.

Comment: I saw that mistake myself and just updated the matrix, thanks! I'm still overlooking how to know if $\beta_1 - \beta_3$ for example, as a question, is estimable. I'm practicing beyond my homework here, trying to memorize ways to figure out estimability. I read that if a given linear combination of the elements of beta can be written as a linear combination of the elements of E(y), then it's estimable.

Comment: OK.  Great work! What is the definition of "estimable?"  You should start with the definition and see how you might be able to determine the estimability of $\beta_1-\beta_3$ from the definition.  Try this for a bit and post back if you have trouble and I'll assist.

Comment: If I try writing $\beta_1 - \beta_3$ I get stuck because my brain is switching over to the $\mu$ vector, and there's 4 $\mu$ and 5 $\beta$ and I can't figure out a way to write an expected value statement that makes sense, like $E(y) = $? what linear combination of elements can I write of the $\mu$'s would work, since the beta and the mu don't match up? I'd start by writing $E(y) = \mu_1 - \mu_3$ but then I don't understand how to write a linear combination so I stop here.

Comment: I think you are making this too hard by writing things in terms of $\mu$.  Don't do that.  Instead, you simply need to answer the question, is there a matrix $C$ such that $CXB$=$\beta_1-\beta_3$?  If you can provide the values for C to get $\beta_1-\beta_3$, you have shown that $\beta_1-\beta_3$ is estimable.

Comment: But I'm not understanding $\beta_1 - \beta_3.$ What is this, do I take the values of these columns of the X matrix and subtract? I don't think this is what it means, and I'm trying to both ask and answer my own questions. Sorry if I sound a little frustrated. I'm at the end of my own understanding.

Comment: No problem.  This is challenging when you are first learning it, so don't get too frustrated.  Most people have a tough time with this.  $\beta_1-\beta_3$ are simply parameters (or the difference of 2 parameters).  The expected value $E(y_{ij})$  is going to be the average difference in score between player i and player j.  The parameters are constants that are unknown in the true model. Then you use regression to estimate these unknown population parameters from your data.  The X-values simply identify the two players who are playing each other &their corresponding y values is the difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34810/discussion-between-statsstudent-and-jennifer-cooke).